# Watching a property of global object in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose that you have an object in the global scope (I know it's bad. It's just for demo purposes), and you want to watch a property of that object in Angular JS.

```
var human = {
    name: 'Somebody'
};
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('watchController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('human.name', function () {
        alert('foo is changed');
    });
    $scope.doWatch = function () {
        human.name = new Date().toString();
    };
});
```

and this HTML:

```
<div ng-app='app'>
    <div ng-controller='watchController'>
        <input type='button' value='Invoke' ng-click='doWatch()' />
    </div>
</div>
```

How do you do that? This code doesn't work. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NrpeG/).

Comment: "I know it's bad" - so don't do it. Map your model objects to view models and watch _those_ instead. Also - to see how watchers work see http://teropa.info/blog/2013/11/03/make-your-own-angular-part-1-scopes-and-digest.html

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - I guess plain curiosity is good enough reason ;)

Answer (score 4):

`$watch` accepts a function as the first parameter. A change in the return value triggers a call to the listener.:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
    return human.name;
}, function () {
    console.log('foo is changed');
});
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ve6Nw/)**</kbd>